# Should a java method accepting long value accept a Integer object?

Tags: java, long-integer

I have a method that accepts a long primitive value and do some processing based on it. It was originally int and changed later. The code where this method is actually called was calling this method with Integer, which was ok earlier becouse of java [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

But after this has been changed to long, my code doesn't show any compile time error while building as i expected. Now if i change it to int instead of Integer, it shows compile time error but not with Integer.

Why is this happening ?

EDIT :

```
class ABC {
   public Customer customerExists(long cid) throws Exception {
   ...
   }
}

class XYZ {
    public void method() {
       Integer customerId = null;
       ...
       customerExists(customerId);
       ...
    }
}
```

This should be a compile time error according to me but its not.

Java Version - 
openjdk version "1.8.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: Can you put a sample code which has the problem??? Also, it would help if you can specify your JDK version... I was not able to reproduce this...

Comment: Can you share a code example so we see exactly what you mean?

Comment: Code, please. And the exact compile error. What you are describing cannot happen!

Comment: 3 upvotes for a question that should be closed because of not having the exact error and the code for reproducing? Additionally, it describes a scenario that simply cannot be? Phhh ... SO is getting weird.

Comment: Are you saying that the compiler doesn't allow you to pass an Integer as a long?

Comment: You can pass a narrow type to a method taking a wide type. i.e., an int/Integer can be passed to a method accepting long/Long. Not the otherway round. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: Does your method have a `Long` argument, or a `long` argument?  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two factors that play role here: Autoboxing and Widening Primitive Conversion.

Autoboxing, or in this case, auto-unboxing, will do implicit conversion between Integer and int.

thanks to this, you can do for example

```
Integer x = 3;
int y = x;
```

Second, java will automatically do the Widening Primitive Conversion when required to the bigger type in following cases:

- method parameter
- arithmetic operations.

Let's show some examples.

Let's say we have `public void testMethod(long x)`
we can call it as follows:

```
 testMethod(2);
```

2, which is integer, will be implicitly mapped to long.
same thing will happen in arithmetic operations, for example:

```
Short s = 1;
int x = s + 1;
```

`Short` will be unboxed to short and then implicitly casted to int (because 1 is int)

Also note that:

```
Short s = 1;
short s2 = s + 1;
```

will not compile, as `s+1` is already int.

If you want to read about it more, check here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score -1):

you can test some changes, to improve your code,  look at this piece of code :

```
class ABC {
   public Customer customerExists(Number cid) throws Exception {
   ...
   if( cid instanceof Integer) {
     cid.intValue().....
   }


   }
}

class XYZ {
    public void method() {
       Integer customerId = null;
       ...
       customerExists(customerId);
       ...
    }
}
```

so you can pass whatever kind of number, take a look at this class to convert in any type number that you need. ( 
[number class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)

Comment: I am not asking for any workaround or solution. I want to know why isn't it a compile time error in java given java is strongly typed.

Comment: @Pankaj ‘Strongly typed’ does not exclude type conversion.